# Um trigger que verifique a data limite de todos os produtos na tabela

Tags: postgresql, administração-postgresql

Boa tarde a todos da comunidade.
Estou tentando fazer uma trigger que verifica os produtos que têm sua data limite expirada e altere o seu status na tabela usando postgresql

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow C J. Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Crie a trigger:

```
-- Function: public.produto_vencido()

-- DROP FUNCTION public.produto_vencido();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.produto_vencido()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 UPDATE public.produto SET ativo = FALSE WHERE validade < NOW()::DATE;
 RETURN 1;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.produto_vencido()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Adicione a trigger na tabela:

```
-- Trigger: validade on public.produto

-- DROP TRIGGER validade ON public.produto;

CREATE TRIGGER validade
  BEFORE UPDATE OF nome, validade, id_produto
  ON public.produto
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.produto_vencido();
```

Comment: Certo, más dessa forma o trigger só vai disparar quando eu fazer um update na tabela certo ? E se isso fosse de como um ciclo, ele ia fazendo a varredura sempre e modificando aqueles produtos que passaram ?

Comment: Na primeira venda do dia vai verificar a sua tabela, não acho necessário ficar verificado continuamente, pois só vai mudar a condição na virada do dia, sugiro fazer um processo de abertura do dia.